# Publisher/subscriber in one python script

Tags: ros, python, dynamixel, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody,

I would like to get some help from you. I want to use a Dynamixel servo but I do not want to have many different files just for listening the positions and setting new goals, so I created the following Python node:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from math import fabs
from dynamixel_msgs.msg import JointState
from std_msgs.msg import Float64

goal_pos = 0;
pub = rospy.Publisher('/tilt_controller/command', Float64)

def transform_callback(data):
    global goal_pos
    rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_name() + ': Current motor angle {0}'.format(data.current_pos))

    # If the motor has reached its limit, publish a new command.
    if fabs(goal_pos-data.current_pos) < 0.01:
        if goal_pos == 0:
            goal_pos = 3.141592
        else:
            goal_pos = 0

        str = "Time: {0} Moving motor to {1}" .format(rospy.get_time(), goal_pos)
        rospy.loginfo(str)
        pub.publish(Float64(goal_pos))


def dxl_control():
    rospy.init_node('dxl_control', anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber('/tilt_controller/state', JointState, transform_callback).
    # Initial movement.
    pub.publish(Float64(goal_pos))
    rospy.spin()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        dxl_control()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

The code is just a union of the simple publisher and listener tutorials adapted to my application.
As I do not have too much experiences programming with ROS (neither Python) I would like to know what do you think about having the publisher and the goal_pos as global variables and also the publisher and the listener in the same node and file.

The plan is that transform_callback will also publish a tf message. Is it ok as it is or would you do it in separate files and nodes?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/107326/publisher/subscriber-in-one-python-script/) by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1305 on 2013-12-05

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After some experience with ROS, and with no other answers, I can say this is perfectly OK and common among ROS nodes.

---

Originally posted by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) with karma: 1305 on 2015-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 13

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jester](https://answers.ros.org/users/25933/jester/) on 2020-07-23**:
is it possible to give rospy.spin a rate?

**Comment by [Hugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/52224/hugo/) on 2021-03-02**:
@jester, yes, it is!
Take a look at this answer: https://answers.ros.org/question/62327/how-to-create-a-combining-subscriber-and-publisher-node-in-python/